# Replace view div with ui-router

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using Angular ui-router for some basic views like so:

```
<div ui-view="header"></div>
<div ui-view="nav"></div>
<div ui-view></div>
```

Currently, the divs are filled with the HTML for the views when Angular loads like so:

```
<div ui-view="header">
  <header>
    <!-- header code -->
  </header>
</div>

<div ui-view="nav">
  <nav>
    <!-- nav code -->
  </nav>
</div>

<div ui-view>
  <main>
    <!-- main code -->
  </main>
</div>
```

I don't want to keep the wrapping divs around the view. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just have it as `<header ui-view="header"></header>` instead? If you are worried about the header then always being present, use a CSS style of `header:empty { display: none }` to hide it completely when it is empty.

Comment: @GregL I want elements like header and nav to be absolutely positioned from the parent element `header` or `nav`. So I would need to apply relevant classes/ids such as `<header ui-view="header" id="header"></header>` Then style `#header { position absolute; }` etc. This is not good modular coding because the html for a view is not contained in 1 file.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `ui-view` directive can be only be done as an element, class or attribute directive (see [the source](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/directives/viewDirective.ts#L193)). Furthermore, it does not use the deprecated `replace: true`. This means that there is no alternative but to have the thing with the `ui-view` directive as a containing element for the contents of the view.

Because of this limitation, I recommend you choose to make an exception to modular coding ideals in this case, and use whatever markup and CSS gives you your desired outcome.